# Не сохраняются данные из полей формы при отправке формы ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

На сайте во всплывающем окне есть форма. На первом шаге заполняются некоторые данные после чего идут на сервер и возвращаются в формате json для использования на следующем шаге. При удачной валидации полей динамически добавляется этаже форма с таким же id но уже с другими полями. Так вот при отправке формы на втором шаге на сервер передаются успешно, но при ошибке валидации данные которые вводил пользователь сбрасываются (не запоминаются), хот я их не затираю, затирание происходит самособой. Не могу понять почему. Можно было бы возвратить переданные данные в формате json и принудительно их прописать полям, но там есть поля для выбора файлов, файлы принудительно вставить туда не получиться. Подскажите почему происходит очистка данных формы

```
    <div class="register-type clearfix">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-value="1" class="active user-type">Документы <br>подтверждения</a><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-value="2" class="user-type">Рекомендация <br>эксперта</a>
        <input id="master-type" type="hidden" name="master-type" value="1">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="Иванов">
    <input type="hidden" name="telephone" value="+38(099) 999-99-99">
    <input type="hidden" name="email" value="38099999999@empty.ua">
    <input type="hidden" name="password" value="1234">
    <input type="hidden" name="customer_group_id" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="newsletter" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="step" value="3">
    <input type="hidden" name="agree" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="customer_group_id" value="2">
    <div class="form-group required custom-field" data-sort="1">
    <label class="control-label" for="custom-field1">Специализация</label>
    <select name="custom_field[1]" id="custom-field1" class="form-control ">
      <option value=""></option>
        <option value="1">Косметолог</option>
        <option value="2">Стилист</option>
    </select>
  </div>
    <div class="form-group row row-file">       
        <div class="col-sm-6">          
            <label class="control-label" for="docs-1">Подтверждающий документ</label>
            <input type="file" required="" name="docs_1" value="" id="docs-1" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif" placeholder="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">          
            <label class="control-label" for="docs-2">Первая страница паспорта</label>
            <input type="file" required="" name="docs_2" value="" id="docs-2" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif" placeholder="">
        </div>
    </div>      
</form>
<button class="btn btn-primary step-2 account-register"><?php echo $button_register; ?></button>
```

JS код

```
$('body').on('click', '#ave-quick-register .account-register', function() {
$.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=extension/module/anystore_login/register',
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: new FormData($('#quick-register')[0]),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#ave-quick-register .form-overlay').addClass('open');
            $('#quick-register .account-register').button('loading');
            $('#ave-quick-register .block-danger').remove();
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#quick-register .account-register').button('reset');
            $('#ave-quick-register .form-overlay').removeClass('open');

            $('.custom-field select').styler();
            $('input[type="file"]').styler({
                filePlaceholder: '<?php echo $entry_download_placeholder; ?>',
                fileBrowse: '<img src="image/cloud-computing.png" alt="" />'
            });
        },
        success: function(json) {

            // очищаем ошибки и уведомления
            $('#ave-quick-register .form-group').removeClass('has-error');
            $('#quick-register .alert').remove();

            // второй шаг
            if(json['step'] == 2 ) {
                console.log("step 2 active");
                html = '<button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>';
                html += '<div class="title"><?php echo $text_master_register; ?></div>';
                html += '<p><?php echo $text_or_login ?> <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-remodal-target="login"><?php echo $text_login_in; ?></a></p>';
                html += '       <form id="quick-register" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-register">';
                html += '<div class="register-type clearfix"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-value="1" class="active user-type"><?php echo $text_master_type_1; ?></a><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-value="2" class="user-type"><?php echo $text_master_type_2; ?></a><input id="master-type" type="hidden" name="master-type" value="1"></div>';

                if (json['data_step']) {
                    $.each( json['data_step'], function( key, value ) {

                        if(key == 'name') {
                            html += '<input type="hidden" name="name" value="'+value+'">';
                        }
                        if(key == 'customer_group_id') {
                            html += '<input type="hidden" name="customer_group_id" value="'+value+'">';
                        }
                        if(key == 'newsletter') {
                            html += '<input type="hidden" name="newsletter" value="'+value+'">';
                        }

                        if(key == 'telephone') {
                            html += '<input type="hidden" name="telephone" value="'+value+'">';
                        }

                        if(key == 'email') {
                            html += '<input type="hidden" name="email" value="'+value+'">';
                        }

                        if(key == 'password') {
                            html += '<input type="hidden" name="password" value="'+value+'">';
                        }
                        
                    });
                }

                html += '<input type="hidden" name="step" value="3">';
                html += '<input type="hidden" name="agree" value="1">';
                html += '<input type="hidden" name="customer_group_id" value="2">';

                // произвольные поля пользователей
                if($('#custom-fields').length) {


                    var custom_fileds = $('#custom-fields').html().replace("not-styler","");

                    $('#custom-fields').remove();

                    html += custom_fileds;
                    
                }

                // поля прикрепления документов
                html += '<div class="form-group row row-file">';

            html += '       <div class="col-sm-6">';
            html += '           <label class="control-label" for="docs-1"><?php echo $entry_docs; ?></label>';
                html += '           <input type="file" required name="docs_1" value="" id="docs-1" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif" placeholder="<?php echo $ntry_download_placeholder; ?>" />';
                html += '<div class="additional-text"><?php echo $text_type_docs; ?><?php echo $text_type_docs_notice; ?></div>';
            html += '       </div>';

            html += '       <div class="col-sm-6">';
            html += '           <label class="control-label" for="docs-2"><?php echo $entry_docs_2; ?></label>';
                html += '           <input type="file" required name="docs_2" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/gif" value="" id="docs-2" placeholder="<?php echo $ntry_download_placeholder; ?>" />';
                html += '<div class="additional-text"><?php echo $text_why_docs; ?></div>';
            html += '       </div>';

            html += '</div>';

                
                html += '<div class="for-alert"></div>';
                html += '       </form>';
                html += '<button class="btn btn-primary account-register step-3"><?php echo $button_register; ?></button>';

            } 

            // вставляем next_step
            if(typeof html !== "undefined") {
                $('#ave-quick-register .remodal-content').html(html);
            }

            if (json['islogged']) {
                 window.location.href="index.php?route=account/account";
            }
            if (json['error_name']) {
                $('#quick-register #register-name').parent().addClass('has-error');
                $('#quick-register #register-name').focus();
            }
            if (json['error_email']) {
                $('#quick-register #register-email').parent().addClass('has-error');
                $('#quick-register #register-email').focus();
            }
            if (json['error_telephone']) {
                $('#quick-register #register-telephone').parent().addClass('has-error');
                $('#quick-register #register-telephone').focus();
            }
            if (json['error_password']) {
                $('#quick-register #register-password').parent().addClass('has-error');
                $('#quick-register #register-password').focus();
            }
            if (json['error_confirm_password']) {
                $('#quick-register #confirm-password').parent().addClass('has-error');
                $('#quick-register #confirm-password').focus();
            }
            if (json['error_code']) {
                $('#quick-register #verify-code').parent().addClass('has-error');
                $('#quick-register #verify-code').focus();
            }

            if (json['error']) {
                $('#ave-quick-register .alert').remove();
                $('#ave-quick-register .for-alert').after('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + json['error'] + '</div>');
            }
            if (json['error_custom_field']) {

                $('#ave-quick-register .alert').remove();

                $.each( json['error_custom_field'], function( key, value ) {
                    $('#custom-field'+key).addClass('has-error');
                    $('#ave-quick-register .for-alert').after('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + value + '</div>');
                });
                
            }
            
            if (json['success']) {
                success = '<button data-remodal-action="close" class="remodal-close"></button>';
                success += '<div class="title">'+json['heading_title']+'</div>';
                success += json['text_message'];
                $('#ave-quick-register .remodal-content').html(success);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    location = json['continue'];
                }, 5000);
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
        var msg = '';
        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
            msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
            msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
            msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
            msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
            msg = 'Time out error.';
        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
            msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
        } else {
            msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
        }
        console.log(msg);
    }
    });
  });

$('#quick-register').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();        
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы пересоздаете форму. Обработчики событий при этом не сохраняются.

```
$(document).on("submit", '#quick-register', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();        
});
```

Comment: не помогло, все равно на втором шаге введенные данные пользователем сбрасываются

Comment: @igorauscas Вы неаккуратно скопировали к себе мой код.